# Any Idea to Extract the String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

How to extract the string below by using one format? Can set the output in uppercase?. Thank you

```
Case 1
Example:
     1. 'T53F1_1-VC1_Car'
     2. 'VC_MOTOR_T33P1_1'
     3. 'T53F2-VC1_Car'
     4. 'VC_MOTOR_T1F3_1'
     5. 'CAR-T09F1_2'
     6. 't1p2_car_vc1'
     7. 'T1f2_car_VC1'

Case 1
Output:
     1. T53F1
     2. T33P1
     3. T53F2
     4. T1F3
     5. T09F1
     6. T1P2
     7. T1F2

(EDIT)
In the case 2 example, any idea how to extract in case dont have the common character like T in example 1.

Case 2
Example:
     1. 'T53F1_1-VC1_Car'
     2. 'VC_MOTOR_Q33P1_1'
     3. 'S21F1-VC1_Car'
     4. 'VC_MOTOR_SS1Q2_1'
     5. 'CAR-T09F1_2'
     6. 'L1p2_car_vc1'
     7. 'T1f2_car_VC1'

Case 2
Output:
     1. T53F1
     2. Q33P1
     3. S21F1
     4. SS1Q2
     5. T09F1
     6. L1P2
     7. T1F2
```

Comment: What database are you using (including version please)?

Comment: You haven't provided any logic that you're trying to implement. My guess "Uppercase the string. Split into tokens of alphanumeric characters, take the first token that begins with 'T'" Is that correct?

Comment: @Phil This is the microsoft sql server 2017 version 14.0

Comment: @BobKaufman Hi Bob, the output string is begin with 'T' and end after the characters 'P' / 'F' . Example TxFx or TxxFx or TxxxFxx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server 2017 then you can use Translate with replace to get the results.

```
select * into #temp from 
(Select 1 as ID,  'T53F1_1-VC1_Car'   as extractvalue union all 
Select 2 as ID,  'VC_MOTOR_T33P1_1'  as extractvalue union all 
Select 3 as ID,  'T53F2-VC1_Car'       as extractvalue union all 
Select 4 as ID,  'VC_MOTOR_T1F3_1'   as extractvalue union all 
Select 5 as ID,  'CAR-T09F1_2'     as extractvalue union all 
Select 6 as ID,  't1p2_car_vc1'    as extractvalue union all 
Select 7 as ID,  'T1f2_car_VC1'    as extractvalue ) tmp

select  ID,Value as   REPLACEDVALUE  from #temp   
CROSS APPLY string_split((TRANSLATE(#temp.EXTRACTVALUE,'_-_', ';;;')),';')  
where value like 'T%'
```

Translate will make sure that all the occurrences of '-' and _ will be replaced with ';' based on your data pattern (it can be changed) to make sure we have ';' in all cases, and then use split string to split the value and use where condition to achieve the results.

Output:

```
   ID   REPLACEDVALUE
    1   T53F1
    2   T33P1
    3   T53F2
    4   T1F3
    5   T09F1
    6   t1p2
    7   T1f2
```

Comment: Why don't you (1) replace the `'-'` with `'_'`  then (2) split with `'_'` and then (3) replace your `like` with `'T%[FP]%'`? Is `translate` is really necessary?

Comment: @sallushan Can you explain to me about this part? 'T%[FP]%'?

Comment: `T%[FP]%` = Begins with T then any character then F or P character then any character